# Canvas downloading as blank image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to save background colors in a table as an image using a canvas.

The list contains 625 background colors (RGBA).

The section of the code for saving the image. '#blank' points to a blank 25 by 25 pixel image

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
    var sourceimage = document.getElementById('blank');
    //sourceimage.style.display = 'none';
    var canvas = document.getElementById('out');
    // canvas.style.display = 'none';
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    function transfer() {
        let pixels = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let imgData = pixels.data;
        let saveData = getSaveDataImage();
        for (let i = 0; i < pixels.data.length; i++) {
            imgData[i] = saveData[i];
        }
        console.log(pixels.data);
        context.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);
    }

    function canvasToImage(ev) {
        let T = ev.target;
        if (T.tagName === 'IMG') {
            canvas.height = T.offsetHeight;
            canvas.width = T.offsetWidth;
            context.drawImage(T, 0, 0, T.offsetWidth, T.offsetHeight);

            transfer();
            url =  canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "pixelPaint.png";

            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    }

    save_.addEventListener('click', function () {
        sourceimage.click();
    })

    document.body.addEventListener('click', canvasToImage, false);
} ,false);
```

If I do the above transfer and then save the canvas using .toDataURL(), I get a blank image downloaded

Why is that happening ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Silly me. Completely forgot to ask my question.

Comment: With the exception of running `getSaveDataImage`, as you don't define that, I cannot reproduce your issue. Calling `toDataURL` gives me a data URL with the image on the canvas.

Comment: Added the full section resposible for the image download

Comment: Having tried the code (replacing `getSaveDataImage` with an arbitrary function) I can open the saved file in GIMP and view the contents, and it is the same as what is rendered to the canvas.

Comment: It's possible that the viewer you are using cannot render the saved image correctly.

Comment: Made a very fundamental mistake: Set the value of A in RGBA to 0 which made the whole thing transparent.